# How to display error From RTK Query mutation

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm new to Redux toolkit query and I'm trying to get and display the error I get from Redux devtools on the frontend but no luck. This documentation wasn't much help.[This is the error message I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBosF.png)

CreateCustomer.jsx

```js
const [addCustomer, {error}] = useAddCustomerMutation();

const onSubmit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setFormData("");
  const customerData = {
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    address,
    phone,
    gender,
    exchange,
    country,
    customerRef,
    description,
    currency,
    currency_symbol
  };

  if (error) {
    toast.error("Something happened")
  } else {
    await addCustomer(customerData)
    navigate("/admin/customers")
    toast.success("Customer created")
  };
};
```

customersApi.js

```js
endpoints: (builder) => ({
  getAllCustomers: builder.query({
    query: () => "/api/v1/customer/paginate-customer",
    transformResponse: (response) => response.payload.data,
  }),
  addCustomer: builder.mutation({
    query: (customer) => ({
      url: "/api/v1/customer/create-customers",
      method: "POST",
      body: customer
    })
  })
})
```